# Add magnifier icon to kendo autocomplete widget

Tags: html, autocomplete, kendo-ui, widget, icons

Is it possible to add a magnifier icon to the kendo autocomplete widget?
http://demos.kendoui.com/web/autocomplete/index.html

By default there is no icon displayed. Only when the user enters a text and 
the widget performs an server-lookup a search-icon is displayed until the data
was returned from the server.

In my case I need a magnifier icon displayed on the right side of the kendo autocomplete
input field so that the user can see that he can search for values in that field. It would be okay if the icon is only displayed when there is no focus on that field.

Can somebody help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You can try the following:

```
$("#auto")
  .kendoAutoComplete()
  .closest(".k-widget")
  .addClass("k-textbox k-space-right")
  .append('<span class="k-icon k-i-search"></span>');
```

Here is a live demo: http://jsbin.com/OREBaRU/1/edit

Comment: Thanks for your help, but actually I meant that the magnifier icon should be displayed INSIDE the input field on the right side, and not next to it. Sorry if my question was not clear enough.

Comment: Well at least this is exactly what I needed... thanks!